# Why below code compiles fine and prints "init"?

Tags: java, class, constructor, object-create

System.out.println("init"); this statement is not within static block and not in any function or constructor, but still java doesn't give any error or warning and prints it before constructor sysout. why ?

```
public class A {

    public A()
    {
        System.out.println("A()");
    }
    public void print(int a) {

        System.out.println("integer");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("init");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestA {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        A a = new A();

        a.print(new Integer(1));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
init
A()
integer
```

Comment: Note that the Java docs provide almost all answers to questions like this.

Comment: @MikeNakis Nope, a static initializer would have the `static` keyword.

Comment: Just look-up for initialization blocks